# Issue with normal mapping

Tags: swift, graphics, 3d, metal

I'm working on implementing normal mapping (using Swift/Metal). However, I think I've made a mistake when calculating the tangent and bitangent, and I can't find the issue.

Here is a screenshot with normal mapping:
[basic shading with normal map & basic shading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nntGF.png), [normal mapping normals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1IvJ.jpg)

And here is a screenshot only using the normals provided by the obj file:
[basic shading without normal map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKV58.png), [normals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9ff7.png).

Here is the code for calculating the tangent and bitangent:

```
func calculateTangentAndBitangent(v1: VertexData, v2: VertexData, v3: VertexData) -> (vec3, vec3) {
        let pos1 = v1.position
        let pos2 = v2.position
        let pos3 = v3.position
        
        let uv1 = v1.uv
        let uv2 = v2.uv
        let uv3 = v3.uv
        
        let e1 = pos2 - pos1
        let e2 = pos3 - pos1
        let x1 = uv2.x - uv1.x
        let x2 = uv3.x - uv1.x
        let y1 = uv2.y - uv1.y
        let y2 = uv3.y - uv1.y
        
        let r = 1.0 / (x1 * y2 - x2 * y1)
        let tangent = (e1 * y2 - e2 * y1) * r
        let bitangent = (e2 * x1 - e1 * x2) * r
        
        return (tangent, bitangent)
}

for i in stride(from: 0, to: vertexBuffer.count, by: 3) {
            let v1 = vertexBuffer[i]
            let v2 = vertexBuffer[i+1]
            let v3 = vertexBuffer[i+2]
            let tb = calculateTangentAndBitangent(v1: v1, v2: v2, v3: v3)
            
            tangents[normalIndices[i]] += tb.0
            tangents[normalIndices[i+1]] += tb.0
            tangents[normalIndices[i+2]] += tb.0
            bitangents[normalIndices[i]] += tb.1
            bitangents[normalIndices[i+1]] += tb.1
            bitangents[normalIndices[i+2]] += tb.1
}
for i in 0..<vertexBuffer.count {
            var v = vertexBuffer[i]
            
            v.tangent = normalize(tangents[normalIndices[i]])
            v.bitangent = normalize(bitangents[normalIndices[i]])
            
            vertices.append(v.vertex)
}
```

Vertex shader:

```
    out.tangent = normalize((modelUniforms.modelMatrix * float4(in.tangent, 0)).xyz);
    out.bitangent = normalize((modelUniforms.modelMatrix * float4(in.bitangent, 0)).xyz);
    out.normal = normalize((modelUniforms.modelMatrix * float4(in.normal, 0)).xyz);
```

Fragment shader:

```
constexpr sampler linearSampler(mip_filter::linear,
                                     mag_filter::linear,
                                     min_filter::linear);
    
    float3 normalSample   = float3(normalMap.sample(linearSampler, in.texCoord).xyz);
    
    normalSample = normalize(normalSample * 2 - 1);
    
    float3 normal = normalize(in.tangent * normalSample.x +
                                   in.bitangent * normalSample.y +
                                   in.normal * normalSample.z);
    
    float3 L = normalize(sceneUniforms.sun.direction);
    float3 NdL = max(dot(in.normal, L), 0.0);
    half3 diff = half3(NdL);
```

I've spent a lot of time looking into this and I still couldn't figure out what the issue is.

Comment: Does your model matrix contain non-uniform scale?

Comment: Never mind my previous comment, you have a mismatch in coordinate spaces you are using for calculations. Your normal, tangent an bitangent are in model space, while your sun direction is probably in world space. Also, you can't just multiply normals by model matrix, especially in cases where there's a non-uniform scale involved, otherwise normals became not normal to the surface. Instead you need to do something like `normalMatrix = transpose(meshUniform.inverseModel * camera.inverseView); out.normalVS = (normalMatrix * float4(in.normal, 0.0)).xyz;`

Comment: I would suggest choosing one coordinate space you want to do all your calculations in and then bring all the other values into that space. Your options are gonna be world space and view space. There are some pros and cons with regards to each one, but I think view space is a bit easier for starters.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :D, the mismatch in coordinate space is because I've tried to minimize the code in the example and mixed up a few things. In the actual app I'm rendering to a gbuffer and doing the lighting calculations on a later stage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `MTKTextureLoader` to load your textures make sure you specify `MTKTextureLoader.Option.SRGB: false` when loading normal maps so that the image data is treated as linear pixel data, else the normals will be all wrong.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metalkit/mtktextureloader/option/1536032-srgb